# I am trying to increase the size of a partion/disk that is full, but I am having trouble

Tags: server, partitioning, 20.04, fdisk

on my Ubuntu virtual machine, I have a disk/partition called `/` with a ton of free space.

I also have a partition called `/mnt/images` that is full.

You can see that here:

```
root@marzen:/# df
Filesystem      1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev              1774696        0    1774696   0% /dev
tmpfs              359172      988     358184   1% /run
/dev/sda1      1040831904  7396580 1033418940   1% /
tmpfs                5120        0       5120   0% /run/lock
/dev/sdb         92703048 92686664          0 100% /mnt/images
root@marzen:/#
```

So I was trying to use `fdisk` to resize, but it gives me this message:

```
root@marzen:/# fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

The old ext4 signature will be removed by a write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x5680ce87.
```

Is there a way of doing this using fdisk or do I need to try something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two separate disks. One is `/dev/sda`, and it contains a single partition `/dev/sda1`, where your root filesystem `/` is mounted. The other disk is `/dev/sdb`, which is not partitioned(!), but instead whole "raw" disk was formatted with a Linux filesystem, and this filesystem is mounted under `/mnt/images`.

So no, you cannot expand the second disk using space from the first disk. That's not supported by any standard filesystem. You could only do this if you had formatted your disks/partitions to use LVM (Logical Volume Manager) during system installation, but you didn't do this.

However, as your whole `/dev/sdb` disk is only around 90 GB, and your root filesystem has around 1 TB of free space, I think the simplest option is the following:

1. create a directory `/mnt/images2` (this will be located within your root filesystem)
2. copy everything from `/mnt/images` to `/mnt/images2`
3. unmount the disk `/dev/sdb` from `/mnt/images` and remove the line that automatically mounts it (if any) from file `/etc/fstab`
4. delete the directory `/mnt/images`
5. rename the directory `/mnt/images2` to `/mnt/images`.

From now on, the directory `/mnt/images` will be part of your main filesystem, and not mounted from a separate disk.

Comment: Quick question... So I created and copied everything to `/mnt/images2`....but when I did a `umount /dev/sdb` I couldn't see `/mnt/images` or `/mnt/images2` I am just wondering what happened....thanks!

Comment: That is strange, because your `df` output shows that only `/mnt/images` is mounted on a separate disk, so `/mnt/images2` shouldn't be affected by the mount. Does `/mnt` exist at all after you unmounted `/dev/sdb` ? Maybe `/mnt` isn't a "normal" directory but some kind of a virtual mount point, handled by some specific software, that appears only when something is mounted? There must be something more to your system configuration than the information you posted here.

Comment: `/mnt/images` is on `/dev/sdb`. I created `/mnt/images2` inside `/mnt`...so that when I `cd /mnt` I can see both `/mnt/images` and `/mnt/images2` . But if I `umount /dev/sdb`, I can't see `/mnt` at all.

Comment: You gave me no new information. As I wrote above, if your system is configured normally, unmounting `/dev/sdb` should not touvh `/mnt`. Both `/mnt` and everything inside `/mnt` should be visible, **including** `/mnt/images` - only that should be empty. If it isn't so, then your `/mnt` isn't what it seems to be. You should investigate in more detail what it actually is.

Comment: Hi Raj, I'm sorry, I'm still learning this system.  I did some reading, I found the `mount` and the `findmnt` commands.  So `mount` shows me this: `/dev/sdb on /mnt/images type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard)` and the `findmnt` command shows me this: `├─/mnt/images                          /dev/sdb               ext4        rw,relatime,discard` To me they look like the same thing, just formatted differently.

Comment: I think I did something wrong following your instructions.  So when I created `/mnt/images2` I created it in the same directory as `/images`.  So both `/images` and `images2` directories are in `/mnt/` But after re-reading your instructions above, do you mean to change my directory to root like this: `cd /`  and then create a new `mnt` folder, and then created `images2` in that?  Thanks for your patience! :)

Comment: You cannot create another `/mnt` folder while one already exists.
The abnormal thing is that whole `/mnt` disappears when you unmount `/mnt/images` only. It SHOULD NOT. Something is strangely configured in your system and `/mnt` seems to be not an ordinary folder. Does `findmnt` show any more lines containing `/mnt` ?

Comment: This is an Ubuntu virtual server on Google Compute Engine services.  I tried a different command that I saw on here and it looks like this: `cat /etc/mtab | grep /dev/sdb` and it found this one line: `/dev/sdb /mnt/images ext4 rw,relatime,discard 0 0`